# How do I make wiris math editor work in CKEditor inline mode?

Tags: plugins, editor, ckeditor, inline

Is there a way to make wiris plugin work in ckeditor v4.0 inline mode? So far in maker adapted it for standard mode only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline mode for CKeditor is working in our development version. Will be included in the next release of WIRIS Plugin.

Please contact WIRIS support team if you are in a hurry at support@wiris.com

Answer (score 2):

Wiris does not support inline editing yet.

Source: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/ckeditor

> CKEditor 4.0 or higher must be in Stardard editor mode. Inline editing
>   mode support will be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

We're glad to announce it works now. 
The WIRIS plugin now supports CKEditor Inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

runs if you remove the condition

plugin.src.js 
line 349 "if (ckeditorIntegrationModelProperties.target) "

Comment: Can you add some more explanation as to why removing this condition makes it work?